# Extract text between first <a> tag

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-match

I have a string

```
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor <a href="http://example2.com">Do not want this text</a> incididunt ut labore et <a href="http://example.com">Want this text</a> dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad     minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in <a href="http://example.com">Do not want this text</a> reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';
```

How can I extract the text between the first instance of an  tag that links to http://example.com?  I don't want the text that links to http://example2.com or the text in the second link that links to http://example.com.

I want to return 'Want this text'.  Any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex PHP, Match all links with specific text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661179/regex-php-match-all-links-with-specific-text)

Answer (score 2):

You can most likely achieve your goal using `DOMDocument` - in conjunction with `DOMXPath` for more complicated requirements.

```
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $str );

$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
if( !empty( $col ) ){
    foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `DomDocument`.
`DomDocument` allows you to use PHP to interact with a HTML page via the Document Object Model.

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; //remove unnecessary whitespace
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
```

At this point, you have an array of objects. Each object is, in essence, an `ElementNode` with tag `a`.

Assuming you want to retrieve the text of the **first** link, you'd then do: 
    `$text = $links[0]->nodeValue;`

However, if you instead want the text that matches the link "http://example.com", then you could do:

```
foreach ($links as $link)
{
  if($link->attributes->href == "http://example.com") {
  $text = $link->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regex, for example:

```
\<a href=\"http:\/\/example.com\".*\>(.*?)\<\/a\>
```

Code snippet:

```
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor <a href="http://example2.com">Do not want this text</a> incididunt ut labore et <a href="http://example.com">Want this text</a> dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad     minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in <a href="http://example.com">Do not want this text</a> reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';

$regex = '/\<a href=\"http:\/\/example.com\".*\>(.*?)\<\/a\>/g';
preg_match($regex, $str, $matches);
```

In $matches you'll find the output you want.

Comment: [you shouldn't use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: @mistermartin way faster and less bugy than DomDocument... As long as you don't need to parse an entire file, regex is better.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.preg-match.php)

Example:

```
$string = '<a href="http://example2.com">Do not want this text</a> incididunt ut labore et <a href="http://example.com">Want this text</a> '; 

if ( preg_match('/<\s*a[^<>]*>([^<>]+)</a>/i', $string, $matches) ) {
       var_dump($matches); 
}
```

Comment: [you shouldn't use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: And why is that ?

Comment: @malutki5200 in case you didn't notice [the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) *mister martin* used in the comment, you should read the answers (and comments) to [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)